# Limiting accessing Web API to application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We're building a cross-platform app using Ionic and using ASP.NET Core WebAPI hosted on azure.
We are using Identity authentication system but we need to restrict access to this API to our application. So if other apps or sites try to access the API they will be blocked. Please note:

- The webapp is SSL secured
- I have been told that sending a shared code
  is not useful as it can be taken from the binary

Kindly give me your suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: IP Whitelisting would be your quickest solution but is not fool-proof if this is an external system. We use IP Whitelisting on some of our API servers on the LAN here as a secondary security measure.

Comment: Use client-credential flow. Or if you have personalized accounts (one for each person) use one of the OpenID flows (i.e. authCode). out of the scope to go further into details

Comment: We use Basic HTTP Authentication implementing AuthorizationFilterAttribute. This will be hit when the call first comes in.

Comment: @lcryder can you please post an example as an answer..... does this account for apps or only from source URL? Thanks

Comment: @ZainAlabdinTawfiq added sample as requested.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a shell of a Authorization Filter.
We send a JSON object that is serialized and encrypted.

Public Class XxxxxxFilter
    Inherits AuthorizationFilterAttribute

```
Public Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(actionContext As System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext)

    Dim authHeader As System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization

    If authHeader IsNot Nothing Then

        '... then check that its set to basic auth with an actual parameter ....
        If String.Compare("basic", authHeader.Scheme, True) = 0 AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader.Parameter) = False Then

            Dim cred As String = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter))

            ' validate the cred value however needed
            ' you want to exit at this point if all is ok

        End If

    End If

    ' ... if we get this far then authentication has failed 
    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)

End Sub
```

End Class