# Very simple web API app - 2 methods - hard code basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple Web API app. Just 2 methods that put (edit or insert data) - I'd like to just hard code basic authentication into the 2 methods without hugely complicating it.

What is the minimum code I need in order to require authentication the two methods - and then how do I use this code (the APIs are called from some C# code in an MVC app).

All of the examples I find online are hugely complicated - with filters or overly elaborate authentication.

My web API methods look something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]ImportObject impobj)
{
// Import data here
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
public async static Task<string> Caller(ImportObject impobj)
{
    string responseString = "NA";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Post new object, get response
        var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("myservice/api/meth", impobj);

        // Get response content string
        var resContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Build user response string (just for testing)
        responseString =
            "<br />result: " + resContent.Result.ToString() +
            "<br />status: " + resContent.Status.ToString() +
            "<br />StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode + "<br />";
    }

    // Output response string
    return responseString;
}
```

I just want to add basic auth to both ends - as it's so simple happy to just hard code it into both methods (this will also let me see easily how it works too).

thx.

Comment: You need to add a filter to your service. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510675/limiting-accessing-web-api-to-application?noredirect=1#comment72177655_42510675. Then you add the 'Authorization: Basic blahblah' in your client prior to calling

Comment: thanks. if you put a c# answer here I will accept it (assuming i can make it work).